# Circle to Hexagon Conversion

Tags: geometry, conversion, coordinate-transformation

I have a set of circles defined by a Middlepoint and a radius
e.g.

```
Circle1: x = 10, y = 10, r = 3
Circle2: x = 15, y = 2, r = 10
etc...
```

But I want to have them converted to Hexagons, do you know any formulas to calculate the 6 edge coordinates for them?

Comment: `Polygon[CirclePoints[6]]`

Comment: Thank you for answering but how to get those 6 points is the question

Comment: did you read the docs for `CirclePoints` ?

Comment: Sorry im quite new to this, where can i find those docs?

Comment: type CirclePoints and press "F1".  The docs are also online: https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/CirclePoints.html

Comment: thank you very much. I will take a look.

Comment: note both `CirclePoints` and `RegularPolygon` are new in v10.1 and 10.2

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The documentation can be found here:  [`CirclePoints`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/CirclePoints.html) or here: [`RegularPolygon`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/RegularPolygon.html).  You can convert a circle into a hexagon via the replacement rule `Circle[x_, y_] :> Polygon[CirclePoints[x, y, 6]]`, or `Circle[x_, y_] :> RegularPolygon[x, y, 6]`

Here it is with 7 random circles,

```
circles = 
  Table[Circle[RandomReal[{-10, 10}, 2], RandomReal[{1, 2}]], {n, 
    7}];
Graphics@circles
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]

```
Graphics[{EdgeForm[Black], FaceForm[None], 
  circles /. Circle[x_, y_] :> RegularPolygon[x, y, 6]}]
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]

Comment: But how do I get the coordinates of them or better where can i draw them like you i cant find it

Comment: What coordinates?  The coordinates for the six points of the hexagon?

Comment: i guess I know how to get those points I saw in the Docs, but where can I draw them like you did?

Comment: Start with this:  `pts = CirclePoints[{1,1},2,6];  Print[pts];  hexagon = Polygon[pts];  Graphics[hexagon]`

Comment: I cant find the Internet Site you are using with it..

Comment: Found it Wolfram Lab.

Comment: You could also do `Circle[x_, y_] :> RegularPolygon[x, y, 6]`

Comment: @ChipHurst Thanks!

Comment: I just did CirclePoints [{x ,y}, radius, 6] for every Circle i have and noted down the coordinates just what i wanted :)